# Simple NLP: How to use ngram to do word similarity?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, nlp

I Hear that google uses up to 7-grams for their semantic-similarity comparison. I am interested in finding words that are similar in context (i.e. cat and dog) and I was wondering how do I compute the similarity of two words on a n-gram model given that n > 2.

So basically given a text, like "hello my name is blah blah. I love cats", and I generate a 3-gram set of the above:

[('hello', 'my', 'name'),
 ('my', 'name', 'is'),
 ('name', 'is', 'blah'),
 ('is', 'blah', 'blah'),
 ('blah', 'blah', 'I'),
 ('blah', 'I', 'love'),
 ('I', 'love', 'cats')]

PLEASE DO NOT RESPOND IF YOU ARE NOT GIVING SUGGESTIONS ON HOW TO DO THIS SPECIFIC NGRAM PROBLEM

What kind of calculations could I use to find the similarity between 'cats' and 'name'? (which should be 0.5) I know how to do this with bigram, simply by dividing freq(cats,name)/ ( freq(cats,*) + freq(name,*) ). But what about for n > 2?

Comment: Why are you saying that "cats" and "name" are 'similar' in your context? Can you define what you mean by "similarity in context"?

Comment: well I am not saying they are similar, but I am just saying I want a score from 0 to 1 which gives me the degree of similarity.
name and cats for example should be around 0.3 which corresponds to barely any similarity but on a big database cats and dogs should roughly be around 0.85 given they are very similar in MOST context.

Comment: I find that your question is not clear. If by context you mean phrases you might try the following: using Python NLTK, using the chunking facility there to locate phrases, no N-grams needed. apply autocorrelation between pairs of such phrases I love dogs and I love cats would have a decent level of correlation. If its really that you want to see how dogs and cats are similar to each other that has nothing to do with N-grams in my opinion. If I were looking fr that measure the easiest way I know of is to use WordNet's graph distance measure to compare dog and cat.

Answer (score 2):

I googled "similarities between trigrams" and came up with [this article](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Trigram/Trigram.pm) which breaks words up into 3 letter segments.  I know that is not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe this will help enough to get you going.

The article also compares 2 words based on the 3 letter approach.  It seems like the comparison would need to be between two search terms, like "hello my name is blah blah. I love cats" and "my name is something else.  I love dogs".  Of course I don't know much about the domain, so if that is incorrect, my apologies, I was just hoping to spur some thought for your question.

Comment: yeah thx, it doesn't really help but I guess the ideas are still there
This article does mainly comparison on character-level ngram

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how google works but one known method is calculating the co-occurrence in documents given words. Taking into account, google has all documents possible then it is pretty easy to calculate that factor and occurrence of a word (frequency) you can then get a bond factor between words. It is not a measure of similarity (like cat and dog) but rather something more collocation.

Take a look:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf–idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)

Another approach would be to drop internet documents, only focus on dictionary entries, there were several attempts to parse those entries and build "common knowledge" system. This way you could get relationships automatically (WordNet and alike are manually crafted).

Comment: This question is specifically asking how you could apply ngram to do semantic similarity. I don't think this is what I am looking for

Comment: Simply don't take whole document into account, but only N-gram. Read "Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing" by Christopher D. Manning and Hinrich Schuetze (chapter about collocation detection, I believe it is relevant to your question).